# Grails executeQuery subquery

Tags: grails, groovy

im using grails 2.4.5

i want to retrieve the top 3 customers based on how many contracts they have

im trying to execute this code

```
def customers = Customer.executeQuery("Select cu, (Select count(*) from Contract co where co = cu.contract) from Customer cu",
                                            [max: 3])
```

and it returns this error

left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [com.cms.Contract : java.util.Set(com.cms.Customer.contract)]

i understand that the co and cu.contract types are not the same but i dont get why. can someone help me how this executeQuery of grails work. this is the only framework i used that have a static query execution but still need to follow a certain format.

what i really want to do is to generate a query like this

```
Select * from Customer cu order by (Select count(*) from Contract co where co.id = cu.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [Criteria](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) query with projections:

```
def results = Customer.createCriteria().list() {
    createAlias( 'contracts', 'contractalias' )
    projections {
        groupProperty( 'contractalias.contract' )
        count( 'contractalias.contract', 'contractCount' )
    }
    maxResults( 3 )
    order 'contractCount', 'desc'
}
```

I'm not 100% of your field names so had to assume in above query.

It's often useful to turn on sql logging when trying out these queries e.g. add following to development DataSource

```
 development {
     dataSource {
     ...
     logSql = true
    }
}
```